# music21: get the voice/program/instrument of midi voice from a flat score?

Tags: python, midi, music21

I have a simple script that uses music21 to process the notes in a midi file:

```
import music21

score = music21.converter.parse('www.vgmusic.com/music/console/nintendo/nes/zanac1a.mid')

for i in score.flat.notes:
  
  print(i.offset, i.quarterLength, i.pitch.midi)
```

Is there a way to also obtain a note's voicing / midi program using a flat score? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MIDI channels and programs are stored on `Instrument` instances, so use `getContextByClass(instrument.Instrument)` to find the closest Instrument in the stream, and then access its .midiProgram.

Be careful:

- `.midiChannel` and `.midiProgram` are 0-indexed, so MIDI channel 10 will be 9 in music21, etc., (we're discussing changing this behavior in the next release)
- Some information might be missing if you're not running the bleeding edge version (we merged a patch yesterday on this topic), so I advise pulling from git: `pip install git+https://github.com/cuthbertLab/music21`
- `.flat` is going to kill you, though, if the file is multitrack. If you follow my advice you'll just get the last instrument on every track. 90% of the time people doing `.flat` actually want `.recurse()`.

Comment: Thank you so much! This is super helpful.